# How to model m:n with 1 optional default value?

Tags: sql, database-design

Below are two schema which I believe achieve the same result, i.e. m:n relationship with the option for a default/preferred value.  Is there any reason to use one over the other?

Schema #1

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id serial,
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE names (
  id serial,
  first_name text not null,
  last_name text not null,
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE person_has_name (
  person_id integer not null references people (id),
  name_id integer not null references names (id),
  is_default boolean not null default false,
  primary key (person_id, name_id)
);
```

Schema #2

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id serial,
  default_name_id integer references names (id),
  primary key (id)
);

-- this table has not changed
CREATE TABLE names (
  id serial,
  first_name text not null,
  last_name text not null,
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE person_has_name (
      person_id integer not null references people (id),
      name_id integer not null references names (id),
      primary key (person_id, name_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze:

- Second schema prevent to you to set more than one `name` as default, but don't prevent to you to set as default `name` some not related name.
- Opposite happens with first schema.

I propose to you (to your zombie user) a third schema that solves math problems:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id serial,
  default_name_id integer , 
  primary key (id),
  constraint default_person_name_fk          --<--HERE
    foreign key (id, default_name_id)
    references person_has_name  (person_id, name_id)
);

-- this table has not changed
CREATE TABLE names (
  id serial,
  first_name text not null,
  last_name text not null,
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE person_has_name (
   person_id integer not null references people (id),
   name_id integer not null references names (id),
   primary key (person_id, name_id)

);
```

Regards and sorry about delay, I'm lag ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the second schema you can't add people without first knowing their name. As long as this is ok (i.e. you know that whenever a person is added, they have to reveal their name), then I'd say that either of these schemas are fine, and that schema #2 might even be more optimized in the scenario where you need to query only for the default name.

Comment: sorry, the FK shouldn't have a not null constraint

Comment: also id like to add, in first schema, person_has_name would need some constraint to ensure there is only one default=true per person_id.  for this reason and the reason you describe i am favouring schema #2 too.

Comment: however, schema #2 has its own problem now i think about it.  should default_name_id also exist in person_has_name table?  it's possible that it won't.

Answer (score 0):

I would use none of the two.

Solution 1 does not prevent you from having 2 default names for a person.

Solution 2 does not prevent a person having a default name that is not his. You could change the Foreign Key from `default_name_id references names(id)` to `(person_id, default_name_id) references person_has_name(person_id, name_id)` but then you'd have circular references and that's another problem, hard to solve.

You could use this, similar to your 2nd solution:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id serial, 
                           --- no  default_name_id as foreign key here
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE names (
  id serial,
  first_name text not null,
  last_name text not null,
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE person_has_name (
  person_id integer not null references people (id),
  name_id integer not null references names (id),
  primary key (person_id, name_id)
);
```

With this extra table, for those persons that have a default name:

```
CREATE TABLE person_default_name (
  person_id integer not null,
  name_id integer not null,
  primary key (person_id),
  foreign key (person_id, name_id) 
    references person_has_name (person_id, name_id) 
);
```

Comment: Your extra table is a 1:1 to people. What is the reason to extract this fields to  the extra table?

Comment: @danihp: Yes, it's a `1:0..1` to people. Only for those that have a default name. The reason is to eliminate circular references between tables.

Comment: Your solution is fine if you either: set `default_name_id` as nullable or: deal with the chichen-and-egg problem when you want to insert into / delete from the `people` and `people_has_name` tables.

Comment: A pity that the question if from Aug 12 '09, and OP 'dead' ;)